Why does acidosis cause cells to remove hydrogen ions using the proton/potassium ion pump rather than exchange with another cation?
Many mammalian cells respond to acidosis by transferring hydrogen ions to the blood using a proton/potassium ion pump. Why is this system employed rather than one involving another cation such as sodium? I ask this because it seems to me that exchange for potassium has the disadvantage of causing hyperkalaemia and therefore potential cardiac problems?

It is hard to know what your question means — you need to reiterate what the Bohr effect is in your opinion and how potassium ions come into it. But the idea that evolution has anything to do with the exchange of ions in molecular processes is absurd — its chemistry. If you can explain your problem clearly, you might consider posting on SE Chemistry.

I meant to ask why is it only potassium that is being exchanged for protons, why not any other cation like maybe sodium or calcium be exchanged for the proton instead. I’ll try to edit the question to better explain what I wish to ask. I had mentioned evolution because I was wondering that maybe there was an advantage of having K+ instead of some other cation be exchanged for H+.
Any input regarding this would be appreciated, thank you!

I have edited your question to reduce it to its essentials, as far as I understand your intent. If I have changed your meaning do make necessary alterations. However the Bohr Effect would seem to be irrelevant and wrong as this involves the uptake of hydrogen ions by haemoglobin. Also there is no reason to refer to evolution in considering the advantages and disadvantages of a particular system, especially as the way you refer to it is very clumsy.

Can you update your question with references to whatever you are reading about the process you're talking about? What type of acidosis, which proton/potassium ion pump are you talking about, what cell type, etc. pH and ionic homeostasis is quite complex.

Isn't the premise itself incorrect, or incorrectly written, that hydrogen ions are 'transferred to the blood' from cells, in exchange for potassium?  The K+ in that case is being excreted by cells.  As for the query itself regarding the specificity of this exchange, H+ for K+ and not Na+, while no doubt complex, this must inevitably relate to the exigency of maintaining an energetically expensive Na+/K+ equilibrium across cell membranes: viz, the excessive extracellular K+ implicated in conditions of acidosis must then be restored to the cytoplasmic compartment via the Na+/K+ ATPase.

I apologise for any misunderstandings, I’m still trying to fully understand the concept. As per what I’ve read online in articles, protons will bind to deoxyhemoglobin in the Red Blood Cell and in order to maintain electrical neutrality, potassium ions will have to exit the RBC. What I meant to ask was why there was the exit of specifically potassium and not any other cation?
A similar doubt I had was regarding the shift of chloride into Red Blood Cells following the exit of bicarbonate from the cells, why specifically Chloride and not any other anion?
